# How to implement infinite scroll in next js?

Tags: pagination, next.js, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll, react-infinite-scroll-component

Infinite scrolling in `next js` is not working, the same code works on normal `create-react-app`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unlike in normal `React Js`, infinite scrolling in `NextJs` has a different approach. Here we will be using an npm package called `react-infinite-scroll-component`.

Let's see the `index.js` file
`index.js`

```
import Content from "./Content";

export default function index(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Content data={props.data} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10"
  ).then((response) => response.json());
  return {
    props: { data }
  };
};
```

In the above code, you can see that we are fetching data from `getStaticProps`, which returns the `json data as props`, and we are receiving that prop and passing it to the component.
If you observe carefully, we are limiting the initial rendering to `10`, so, first 10 data will be shown and then we'll again fetch `data` from the server.

Now, let's see the content page
`Content.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const Content = ({ data }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(data);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  const getMorePost = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_start=${posts.length}&_limit=10`
    );
    const newPosts = await res.json();
    setPosts((post) => [...post, ...newPosts]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={posts.length}
        next={getMorePost}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loader={<h3> Loading...</h3>}
        endMessage={<h4>Nothing more to show</h4>}
      >
        {posts.map((data) => (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <div className="back">
              <strong> {data.id}</strong> {data.title}
            </div>
            {data.completed}
          </div>
        ))}
      </InfiniteScroll>
      <style jsx>
        {`
          .back {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            color: white;
            margin: 10px;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Here we are getting more posts from the server after all the data loads. The code is self-explanatory.

```
setPosts((post) => [...post, ...newPosts]);
```

With the above state, we are appending the previous data to the incoming data

You can check this code sandbox for the visual of how it is actually working.

> https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-infinite-scroll-3vfem

Comment: so we gave up on pre-rendering the page, right ? or how can we implement a page like pre-render 10 posts, the rest will come from `getMorePost()` ?

Comment: now we are doing client side for infinite scroll? won't that reveal API urls in client side?

Comment: @JatinHemnan You can create an api route for it and call it from your api, no?

Comment: @Syph you mean like /api/something
yeah that will work